# Django Combining __unaccent and __search Lookups

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

So I am trying to use `__unaccent` and `__search` in the same model filter, but I receive an error when doing so. I am trying to make a filter using the term "Pokemon" match the term "Pokémon" (notice the "é")

`Game.objects.filter(title__unaccent__icontains="Pokemon")` works fine, but when I use `Game.objects.filter(title__unaccent__search="Pokemon)`, I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError at /autocomplete-games/ function unaccent(tsquery)
>
> does not exist LINE 1: ...ALESCE(UNACCENT("main_game"."title"), ''))
>   @@ (UNACCENT(p...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.

I am using:

Python 3.5

Django 1.10

PostgreSQL (unaccent extension installed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to define custom search configuration in database like:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION unaccent ( COPY = french );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION unaccent ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word WITH unaccent, simple;
```

I am not a postgres expert, but this configuration works for me. For more details check tutorial like this: http://www.nomadblue.com/blog/django/from-like-to-full-text-search-part-ii/

and than use this in Django:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery

Game.objects.annotate(unaccent_title=SearchVector('title', config='unaccent')).filter(unaccent_title=SearchQuery('Pokemon', config='unaccent'))
```

Comment: It looks like `__search` is not deprecated, and in fact supports PostgreSQL, as per the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/search/#postgresql-support - any idea why the docs contradict itself?

Comment: Ow, I see, looks like they've deprecated mysql search and introduced postgres one in the same version :). I will take a look at this and will let you know if I find out anything.

Comment: That explains it! If you can show me a custom solution I would much appreciate it and be happy to award the bounty

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I modified it a bit but it now works perfectly :)