# django error while searching in unaccent way

Tags: django

models.py

```
class KeySkills(models.Model):
    skills            = models.TextField()
    versions          = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,default=None)
    experience        = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,default=None)
    user              = models.ForeignKey(access_models.SeekerRegister,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='key_skills',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "KeySkills"
```

query:

```
KeySkills.objects.filter(skills__unaccent__icontains='python')
KeySkills.objects.filter(skills_text__search='python')
```

error:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1080, in build_lookup
    lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1126, in try_transform
    (name, lhs.output_field.__class__.__name__))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'unaccent' for TextField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Here i am trying to search using django ORM queries.
And tring using above two way of queries but i am getting above error .

Please have a look into my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `'django.contrib.postgres`' in your `INSTALLED_APPS`
Also, try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421706/django-combining-unaccent-and-search-lookups)

Comment: I am using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'django.contrib.postgres' in your INSTALLED_APPS:
and after that you need install the extension 'unaccent' to you database to do this  execute tha query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

i did this inside pgadmin4 in execute query.